# Cannot invoke function even when all parameters are correct

Tags: swift

I'm trying to invoke this function, where **DataObject** is a protocol that **User** uses:

```
static func makePostRequest<T:DataObject>(to endpoint:String, dataObject: T, objectType: T.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (DataObject?, Error?) -> Void) {
//some code
}
```

But I can't invoke it with this parameters:

```
static func create<T : DataObject>(_ object: T, completionHandler: @escaping (DataObject?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let endpoint = NetworkManager.shared.baseURL + UserDAO.methodPath
        NetworkManager.makePostRequest(to: endpoint, dataObject: object, objectType: User.self, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
```

An error appears to me saying I can't invoke it with this list of parameters, but all of them are correct... I really don't know what's happening.

Error:

> Cannot invoke 'makePostRequest' with an argument list of type '(to: String, dataObject: T, objectType: User.Type, completionHandler: (DataObject?, Error?) -> Void)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to call it like this, at least it worked for me in playground.

```
makePostRequest(to: endpoint, dataObject: object, objectType: T.self, completionHandler: completionHandler)
```

---

or add other generic variable

```
func makePostRequest<T: DataObject, U>(to endpoint:String, dataObject: T, objectType: U.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (DataObject?, Error?) -> Void)
```

I do not know what are you trying to achieve, so this might not help you at all

Comment: Adding another generic variable worked! Thank you very much!